# cannot set the text of label in DetailViewController after passing data between different viewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

pass data from FirstViewController to DetailViewController. i can not set the text of label in DetailViewController; FirstViewController is a tableview and it is good.

i use method updateRowNumber to set the rowNumber . and in DetailViewController, i can use debugger to see the rowNumber is correct. but the label's text is not showed on the view.

anyone can help me out?

in my FirstViewController

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (dvController == nil)
{
    DetailViewController *aController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.dvController = aController;

    [aController release];
}   

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
[dvController updateRowNumber:indexPath.row];


}
```

in my DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
{
    int rowNumber;
    IBOutlet UILabel *message;
}

@property(readwrite) int rowNumber;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *message;
- (void) updateRowNumber:(int) theindex;


@end
```

in my DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"


@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize message, rowNumber;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void) updateRowNumber: (int) theindex
{
    rowNumber = theindex + 1;
    message.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %i was clicked", rowNumber];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [message release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    message.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %i was clicked ", rowNumber];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //message.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %i was clicked ", rowNumber];

    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear: animated];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you set IBOutlet to your label in xib?

Comment: i do not use xib, i use programmatically

Comment: You have neither created label nor added on view. Check following code

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    message = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
    [self.view addSubview:message];
    message.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %i was clicked ", rowNumber];
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to learn how the view is loaded, the process is well described in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html)

What happens is that the `view` and all the outlets are `nil` until the `view` is loaded, you can make sure it is loaded by calling `self.view;` before configuring the outlet at `updateRowNumber:`

---

Please also note, you are better to call `[super viewDidLoad]` in the beginning of the overridden  `viewDidLoad`, it makes sense as you need to let  `UIViewContorller` to do it's staff before you do some customized logic, the `dealloc` is different as you need to do your logic before the standard `NSObject -dealloc` fires. Hope it's understandable.

Comment: i can make the label to be seen.  but the rowNumber's value from the firstViewController is lost
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 20.0, 200.0, 50.0)];
    label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %i was clicked ", rowNumber];
    [self.view addSubview:label1];
    
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

Comment: the doc is userful, thnx A-Live